# What could A, F and L mean in a course timetable?

Tags: abbreviation

I've found a timetable for sports courses. The columns seem to describe ID, time and something more. What could A, L and F mean?

```
Badminton

10101   L       Mo  20.00-21.30
10102   A       Di  17.00-18.30
10106   A       Do  17.00-18.30
10108   A       Di  17.00-18.30
10109   F       Di  17.00-18.30

Basketball

10301   A           Mo  17.00-18.30
10302   F           Mo  17.00-18.30
10303   L Frauen    Mo  18.30-20.00
10304   L Männer    Mo  18.30-20.00
10305   F           Di  18.30-20.00
10308   F Frauen    Do  17.00-18.30
10309   F Männer    Do  18.30-20.00
```

[The actual table](http://sportan3.zhs.ze.tum.de/angebote/aktueller_zeitraum_0/kurssuche.html) does not provide column titles or a legend.

Other texts are written at some rows, such as "freies Spiel" and "Auswahl". This leads me to think that that's what A and F stand for. However, it doesn't explain L, and it wouldn't make much sense to abbreviate some cells but not others.

Comment: Ich votiere nicht für 'close', da mir die Frage durch 'usage' abgedeckt scheint. Es ist ein Rätsel welches aber inzwischen eine, ich denke objektive, Lösung gefunden hat, und nicht im wilden Spekulieren endet. Der Informationsgehalt für Dritte ist sicherlich gering, so dass man mit "too localized" natürlich argumentieren könnte. Mehr Kommentare zu den close-votes sind erwünscht. Zustimmung kann dann ja durch aufwerten des Kommentars ausgedrückt werden.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To quote the site:

> Badminton Anfänger (A) und Fortgeschrittene (F) wird im Sommersemester in 2 Kursreihen mit jeweils
>   6 (bzw.5) Terminen angeboten. Das Leistungstraining (L) findet über das gesamte Semesterprogramm statt.

So A stands for beginners, F for intermediates and L seems to be a program with consecutive courses.

Comment: Hm, perhaps I should have thought of looking at the badminton-specific page :) Thanks!

Comment: Some pages (like badminton) have an explanation, while others (like basketball) just omit it. So it is not your fault ;)